# Loop Through Dynamic Filtered List

Tags: vba, excel

how would I loop through visible rows in a filtered list? I have a cell in the first filtered row in let's say column B that is a "Y". I need to be able to change all non-hidden cells in a specific column to be Y. This needs to be dynamic too because the column B range is going to be different everyday.

Essentially, I Need to modify this code:

```
Range("B2").Select --Where B2 is "Y"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(*This is where I am unsure*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here with Autofill, but this will give you an idea about how to deal with filtered cells...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim FillWith As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet    'Change it as per your requirement
lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
FillWith = ws.Range("B2").Value     'Change it as per your requirement
If ws.FilterMode Then
    If ws.Range("B1:B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        ws.Range("B2:B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = FillWith
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am not following the lr variable. What are we trying to do there?

Comment: lr variable holds the last row used on the sheet i.e. last row with data and this is essential when you need to check if some rows are visible after applying the filter criteria and as per your requirement, you only need to fill the visible cells in column B after applying the filter criteria. The IF condition in the code checks whether some rows are visible after the filter is applied and if meets the criteria, then only the code will fill the visible cells in column B.

Comment: @studentofarkad You're welcome! Glad it worked. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)

Comment: I did it by updating the title but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to visible cells only using `SpecialCells`

```
Range("A2:A100").SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Comment: Hm... that's even easier than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173445/excel-vba-filtered-visible-cell, which i was about to link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out.

Comment: No problem - happy to help