# Change filtered cell background color for that filtered values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

If I filter data in column 2, I wanted to change the filtered row/s background color. Is it possible?
My intention is, if there is any filter on the column then I want to show that differently.

please see pictures below of the results I wanted to achieve:

[Choosing values to Filter in Column 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar2Q0.png)

[On change Color on Filtered Rows(Yellow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th3v4.png)

[Rows will go back to Original state when there is no filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1isxb.png)

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62054627/4101210

Comment: I'm new to macro. & I try to  copy the codes and paste it to my worksheet from the link you provided but it didn't work :( @Mech

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub TESTColorFilteredRange()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, rngF As Range
  Dim filtCol As Long          'column to be filtered
  Dim filterCriteria As String 'set here your filter criteria
  
  filtCol = 1 'column A:A. Change here according to your need
  filterCriteria = "A" 'Set it your criteria. I ued "A" for testing reason...
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
  sh.cells.AutoFilter  'clear te filter if it exists
  lastR = sh.cells(Rows.count, filtCol).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on the column to be filtered
  Set rng = sh.Range(sh.cells(1, filtCol), sh.cells(lastR, filtCol)) 'set the range to be filtered
  rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & filterCriteria 'filter the range
  Set rngF = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)  'set the filtered cells range
  rngF.Interior.Color = vbYellow                  'color the filtered range interior
  NotIntersect(rng, rngF).Interior.Color = xlNone 'uncolor the not filtered range interior
End Sub

Function NotIntersect(rng As Range, rngF As Range) As Range 'determines the not filtered range
  Dim rngNI As Range, i As Long
  For i = 1 To rng.Rows.count
    If rng.cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        If rngNI Is Nothing Then
            Set rngNI = rng.cells(i, 1)
        Else
            Set rngNI = Union(rngNI, rng.cells(i, 1))
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  If Not rngNI Is Nothing Then Set NotIntersect = rngNI
End Function
```

Test it and send some feedback, please.

`NotIntersect` is necessary to clear the coloring on the not filtered range. Otherwise, **after some tests using different criteria, all the range cells will be colored**...

Comment: Do I need to assign this in a button?

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: You may assign it to a button, or simple run it from VBE (Visual Basic for Application Editor) pressing F5 (in order to test it). It can be run from an event, from a lot of controls in a lot of ways...

Comment: Can it run immediately after you filter the column?

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: the code itself filters the column... Look attentive to the code and choose the `filtCol` and `filterCriteria` according to your needs. Each line of the code is commented, explaining what it does... My test code filters column A:A and use "A" as filter criteria. But you probably need to use something different... Or, put some "A" (without double quotes...) in column A:A and just test it

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: Didn't you find time to test the code? You used to be extremely responsive until I told you how to proceed...

Comment: Might be sleeping :)

Comment: @Mech: Maybe... :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Your code works :D What if I don't want to set the filterCriteria? It willl depend on what value I will select in the filter? @FaneDuru

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: I am not sure I understand what you mean... **The above code colors the visible cells of the range in A:A** and clear the color for the hidden cells in the range. The range in discussion means A1:A last row. The filter is only a tool to hide some rows... And It can be eliminate by simple commenting the line `rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & filterCriteria`. Can you better describe what you need, in fact?

Comment: @FaneDuru: for example I wanted to filter column A:A that has a value "B" . the filtered data will change background color. but the filterCriteria =  "A" is only limited to the values that is only declared to the code right?  is it possible to automatically get the value that you filtered without manually declaring it one by one?

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: Now, I am even more confused... "A" is only an example used by me when made some tests. It should be what criteria you want, if it exists in the range to be filtered. Now, if not this is your problem, what do you mean by "is it possible to automatically get the value you're going to filter"? VBA is not a mind reader... If you are able to define **an algorithm based on what a criteria to be chosen**, it can be done. But you must define this allocating algorithm. Can you?

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: Hello! Again Silenzio Stampa? Did you clarify what you want? Defining the algorithm means to explain it in words...

Comment: @FaneDuru: Thank you for your concern. Sorry because I didn't clearly explain what I wanted to do as I am new to Macro. Please see attached pictures above for the result I wanted to achieve. I'm still trying to look for ways.

Comment: @Yumi Hamano: Your "new" question can be reflected in an adapted code. But, since I do not find any meaning in such a behavior, I feel I am wasting my time. Have a nice day, then!

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I have two different criteria on the same column and I need to color each criteria with different color?